# Как читать текст отдельно от основного кода?

Tags: c#

Есть метод

```
 void decode(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
        if (result != null)
        {
            SetResult(result.Text);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return;

    }
```

Его необходимо вызывать Кнопкой
Я испробовал 3 варианта

1)

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decode(); //ошибка
    }
```

2)

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        decode(sender, eventArgs);
    }
```

Ошибка такова - *нет перегруженного метода для button1 click который соответствует делегату eventhandler*

3)

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs = null;
        decode(sender, eventArgs);
    }
```

В этом случае ошибок в коде не имеется, но
после запуска выдается ошибка в этом фрагменте

```
ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
```

*system nullreferenceexception ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр*

Я точно знаю, что  *NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs = null;* не равно null, но  не знаю что туда записать.

Суть такова, программа читает QR-код и выводит надпись в TextBox, Как только нужный текст появляется, то нужно выполнить действие. но так как считывание непрерывно, действие повторяется бесконечно, до того момента как QR-код сменится

---

Исходный код для других вариантов решения

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using ZXing;



namespace Сканер_QR
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    private ZXing.BarcodeReader reader;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    delegate void SetStringDelegate(String parametr);

    void SetResult(string result)
    {
        if (!InvokeRequired)
            tbText.Text = result;
        else
            Invoke(new SetStringDelegate(SetResult), new object[] { result });
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);


        if (videoDevices.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                lbCams.Items.Add(device.Name);
            }
            lbCams.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

    }

    private void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[lbCams.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pbWedCamPrev.Image = bitmap;

        decode(sender, eventArgs);


    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoSource != null)
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource.WaitForStop();
        }
    }
    void decode(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)

    {
        ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());

        if (result != null)
        {
            SetResult(result.Text);

        }

    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decode(); 
    }


}
}
```

Comment: У вас не верно реализован сам метод decode. Параметр sender не используется. И сам метод обрабатывает только eventArgs.Frame.Clone() Создайте метод, который работает этим параметром и вызывайте его.

Comment: @becouse , Я не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду, можно-ли немного подробнее?

Comment: вы уверены что "заморозить" UI на две секунды (`Thread.Sleep(2000);`) хорошая идея? Ваш метод похож на обработчик события, а событие соответствующее присутствует? Если присутствует то инициируйте событие, обработчик будет вызван, если конечно подписан на событие. В противном случае проще написать обычный приватный метод, который будет работать с нужной вам картинкой без всяких `<some>EventArgs`

Comment: Я только учусь, и мне совершенно не ясны данные Коментарии. Если кто, сможет объяснить простыми словами буду признателен

Comment: Ок, попробую проще. Откуда вообще взялся ваш метод, который вы не можете вызвать, точнее даже не сам метод, а список его параметров? Если его писали вы, то вероятно преследовали какую-то цель, только пока не понятно какую.

Comment: @rdorn , я уже решил задачу, но если возможно будет так как обозначено в вопросе, то программа читает QR-код и выводит надпись в TextBox, Как только нужный текст появляется, то нужно выполнить действие. но так как считывание непрерывно, действие повторялось бесконечно, до того момента как QR-код сменится

Comment: Ну вы же как-то отдаете команду на считывание? Значит и команда на прекращение считывания должна быть. Я не знаком с библиотекой, которую вы используете, но сильно сомневаюсь, что в ней все так плохо. Хуже всего то, что вашего кода недостаточно. чтобы посторонний человек мог воспроизвести вашу проблему у себя, поэтому столько вопросов и, возможно, не очень понятных комментариев.

Comment: @rdorn , Выложил исходный код

Comment: Лучше перенести в вопрос [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1031848/edit). Но в целом понятно, вы повесили декодирование на захват кадра. Ваш метод является обработчиком события получения кадра камерой. С ходу не напишу как тут правильно поступить, но в документации должен быть соответствующий пример. Посмотрим...

Comment: https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/ тут посмотрите. В проекте есть пример WinForms приложения работающего как с отдельными картинками, так и с камерой. И никаких бесконечных циклов.

Comment: @rdorn , Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Сигнатура вашего метода:

```
void decode(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
```

То есть в него нужно передать `object` и `NewFrameEventArgs`.
Естественно, вызвать его без параметров - `decode()` - невозможно.

В этом фрагменте:

```
NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs = null;
decode(sender, eventArgs);
```

правильно передаются типы: `object` и `NewFrameEventArgs`. Только нужно задать значения второму параметру вместо `null`.

Я не знаю, какие конструкторы есть у этого типа, но в общем должно быть что-то вроде:

```
NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs = new NewFrameEventArgs();
```

Посмотрим, что происходит внутри этого метода:

```
ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
```

Из свойства `Frame` извлекается изображение и передаётся на обработку.
Значит, вы должны задать этому свойству какое-либо изображение. Что-то вроде:

```
NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs = new NewFrameEventArgs();
eventArgs.Frame = new Bitmap(1, 1); // для примера создаётся изображение размером 1*1
decode(sender, eventArgs);
```

Также из кода видно, что в методе `decode` параметр `sender` никак не испоьзуется, поэтому можно писать:

```
decode(null, eventArgs);
```

Конечно, возникает вопрос: какую картинку использовать вместо `Bitmap(1, 1)`? Это можете знать только вы. Вы же вызываете этот метод. А он декодирует картинку. Вот что вы хотите декодировать, то и передавайте.

---

Как вариант, можно добавить перегрузку метода:

```
void decode(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
    if (result != null)
    {
        SetResult(result.Text);
    }
}
```

И в событии нажатия кнопки вызывать его:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    decode(bitmap);
}
```

Вопрос, что именно передавать вместо `Bitmap(1, 1)` остаётся прежним.

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос более не актуален. Решил задачу другим способом. С помощью второго потока.

Добавил переменную

```
 string proverka;
```

Создал второй поток

```
 void decode(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)

    {
        ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());

        if (result != null)
        {
            SetResult(result.Text);
            proverka = result.Text;
        }

    }
    void test()
    {
        Task Potok2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (proverka == "qwe")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("qwe");
                    proverka = ""; 
                }
            }
        }); 
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test(); 
    }
```

Comment: Жесть... Просто нет слов)

Comment: 1. `Task` - это не поток! 2. Где вы тут хоть как то затрагиваете метод `decode`? У вас будет бесконечно крутиться цикл с вашей проверкой, да и все.. Где решение то?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , ну незнаю-незнаю. Все работает